# XMLHttpRequest() Malformed Post Header HTML5 Upload

Tags: php, ajax, perl, xmlhttprequest

I am using the following code to upload files from a phone to a web server. If I remove the ajax call and use the form only the upload works. If I use ajax the PHP or CGI scipts I use to handle the upload fail. CGI gives me a malformed post header error.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function uploadFile() {

    var fd = new FormData();

          var count = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files.length;


          for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++)

          {

                 var file = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[index];
                 alert(file.name);

          } 

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.open("POST", "upload.pl");

    xhr.send(fd);

  }

  function uploadProgress(evt) {

    if (evt.lengthComputable) {

      var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);

      document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';

    }

    else {

      document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';

    }

  }

  function uploadComplete(evt) {


    alert(evt.target.responseText);

  }

  function uploadFailed(evt) {

    alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");

  }

  function uploadCanceled(evt) {

    alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");

  }

</script>


    <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.pl">
    <div>
      <label for="fileUpload">Take or Select Images</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" accept="image/*" capture="camera" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
    </div>
    <div id="details"></div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" value="Upload" />
    </div>
    <div id="progress"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Standard ajax cannot do file uploads. The usual workaround is to close the form fields into a hidden iframe and do a convention form submission there.

Comment: Unless I missed something, you're not actually sending anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never populated `fd` with any data! From what I read in [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects),

```
var fd = new FormData();
```

should be

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('form1'));
```